# getMyTopTracks from spotify-web-api-js not working

Tags: angular, spotify

I have been trying to get my top tracks using this in Typescript and Angular:

`async getDefault2(){ let tracks = await this.authService.getApi().getMyTopTracks({ time_range: "medium_term", }); console.log(tracks) }`

The strange part is that the only method that is actually working is getMe() and I don't know why! I always get a 403 error!

I have been trying to add params to the get but id doesn't work!

Comment: This is most likely a network related issue, You have to check if there is a firewall application that guards your local network.